# PayPal Instant Payment Notification for Held Payments

Tags: asp.net, api, paypal, paypal-ipn

So I'm using an API to receive payment notifications,

I don't really care what's in the notification I just want paypal to notify the API when a payment has been made and execute my own code.

So first off is this even going to work?

I put the URL for the API in the Instant Payment Notification under my account settings. My account is still new because I sent a test payment and it didn't work, do held payments not notify the IPN?

Answer (score 1):

If the payment is held within PayPal it will notify via IPN, yes. You will be able to see such held payments by logging into [www.paypal.com](http://www.paypal.com) and viewing the activity. There will also be a "pendingreason" value in the IPN, to notify you of why it is held.

Note that if at transaction time a "notify_url" is set by the integration (many older shopping carts do this), that URL will be used in place of whatever is set at the account level in [www.paypal.com](http://www.paypal.com). Whatever was set at transaction time has precedence.

--

If an order is "on hold" by your shopping cart (pending payment), PayPal will not send any notification as nothing has taken place within its system (except maybe a checkout attempt that was clicked on but not finished for whatever reason)